# Angular4 routerLinkActive is not set when route is called from the address bar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to make a sub navigation which would be highlighted according to the current route. The html file is defined as

https://github.com/SayakMukhopadhyay/elitebgs/blob/7e6da91ca51f4d98c8553c84a02f755b30caf10d/src/app/main/main.component.html

My issue is when I am going to the route `/faction/:id` using a link, the routerLinkActive is keeping the active class correctly. But if I go to the route directly from the address bar, its not assigning the `active` class for highlighting. I am guessing that this is some issue regarding incorrect events order. What am I missing?

EDIT: So I installed Augury extension for chrome and inspected the source. When I going to the route `/faction/:id` through a link, `RouterLinkActive.active` is coming to be `true` but on calling the same route from the address bar, its becoming `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc `faction` will not activate when you navigate to `faction/:id`, you defined two completely different routes for those paths:

```
        {
            path: 'faction',
            component: FactionListComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'faction/:factionid',
            component: FactionViewComponent
        }
```

To archive what you want, you could use the following as starting point:

```
       {
            path: 'faction',
            children: [
              {path: '',component: FactionListComponent},
              {path:':id',component: FactionViewComponent}
            ]
        }
```

Comment: If my understanding was correct, then `routerLinkActive` applies the selected class whenever the `routerLink` or any of its child routes are active. In this case I have used ```<button routerLink="/faction" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-link nav-link nav-item">Factions</button>``` so I was believing that `/faction` and `/faction/<someid>` both would activate the associated `routerLinkActive`

Comment: nope, to archive that you would need to define childrens of faction. Ill update my answer

Comment: I have made edits, but there is no change. I am already using child routes in another component and facing the same issue so I don't think it is because of absence of child routes https://github.com/SayakMukhopadhyay/elitebgs/blob/7e6da91ca51f4d98c8553c84a02f755b30caf10d/src/app/eddb_api/eddb-api.component.html

Comment: To clarify, in the last component, `api/elitebgs/docs` route is not having the `active`  class as used by `routerLinkActive` even though it is given as a child of `api/elitebgs`